# Aurelia Getting Repeat.for converted array length and using it in if.bind

Tags: arrays, typescript, aurelia

How can I get length of filtered array called `falilid` inside `repeat.for` and then use this length as condition for `.files-message` div? If this length is `undefined, false, 0, null` and etc. message should be shown else should be hidden. I have tried to write `ref` for `.white-box`, tried to bind new property where I save filtered array and then using it inside condition... but didn't help. Any ides? Looking for your help

```
  <div class="elem" if.bind="!elem.children.length">
        <div class="files-wrapper">

        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="white-box" repeat.for="fail of failid | filterOnProperty:'elemId':elem.parent.id | filterOnProperty:'remove':false" >
                <elem-fail if.bind="fail != null" fail.two-way="fail" on-fail-eemaldatud.call="failRemoved(fail)"></elem-fail>
            </div>

            <div class="files-message">Some  message</div>

            <editable-file-upload liik-kl-oid.bind="elem.parent.id" on-file-uploaded.call="failUploaded(liik.parent.id, subelem.id, failiViitedId, file)">Lae üles</editable-file-upload>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the filtered array in a parent property and then use this property in the `repeat.for` and `if.bind`. For example:

```
<div class="form-inline" ref="myForm" fails.bind="failid | filterOnProperty:'elemId':elem.parent.id | filterOnProperty:'remove':false">

  <div class="white-box" repeat.for="fail of myForm.fails">
    <elem-fail if.bind="fail != null" fail.two-way="fail" on-fail-eemaldatud.call="failRemoved(fail)"></elem-fail>
  </div>

  <div class="files-message" if.bind="myForm.fails.length">Some  message</div>

  <editable-file-upload liik-kl-oid.bind="elem.parent.id" on-file-uploaded.call="failUploaded(liik.parent.id, subelem.id, failiViitedId, file)">Lae üles</editable-file-upload>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome solution!